# Sqlite Check if Table is Empty

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Well, I have a databse and it has lots of table. but generally tables are empty.
I want check if a database table is empty.
IF table is empty, program will fill it.

```
public static long queryNumEntries (SQLiteDatabase db, String table)
```

I will use it but it requre API 11.

Comment: Note that the `queryNumEntries(db:table:)` method was added in API level 1; it's the `queryNumEntries(db:table:selection)` and `queryNumEntries(db:table:selection:selectionArgs)` methods which were added in API level 11. See the [android.database.DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils) Android Developers page for reference.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you can execute `select count(*) from table` and check if `count> 0` then leave else populate it.

like

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();
String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM table";
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
mcursor.moveToFirst();
int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
if(icount>0)
//leave 
else
//populate table
```

Comment: well it is working. I have modified a little bit but I dont know It will accour problem in the future. I have deleted first line `SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();` and at the beginning of class I have defined my database as **static** like this: `private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;`

Comment: you can declare that way too but why do u define static.?

Comment: because of eclipse suggestion

Comment: this is not a optimal solutions, As all knows count method take more process to execute a query, Please use select exists query instead of count()

Comment: This works good. I put mine in a method that returns an int and assigned the cursor value to the returning value. Then I used this method in a if statement based on its returning value and if it equaled 0 do stuff else do nothing so to speak. I had to add some logging to the if sections just to track its steps in the DDMS and filtered the tags for clear reading tag:Database Operations. i.e. Log.v(TAG, "Some table is not empty"); thanks @Waqar Ahamed

Comment: Why `getWritableDatabase()`? You are just reading the data.

Comment: @Apurva..because if table will empty then we need to write data in table, so for that i use getWritableDatabase.

Answer (score 11):

Do a `SELECT COUNT`:

```
boolean empty = true
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOURTABLE", null);
if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    empty = (cur.getInt (0) == 0);
}
cur.close();

return empty;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
 public boolean isEmpty(String TableName){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long NoOfRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database,TableName);

    if (NoOfRows == 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `if` clause you can simply do `return NoOfRows == 0;`

Comment: For the curious: the `DatabaseUtils` class referenced in this answer is the [android.database.DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils) class.

Answer (score 7):

Optimal Solutions

```
public boolean  isMasterEmpty() {

    boolean flag;
    String quString = "select exists(select 1 from " + TABLE_MASTERS  + ");";

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(quString, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count= cursor.getInt(0);
    if (count ==1) {
        flag =  false;
    } else {
        flag = true;
    } 
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better option:

```
public boolean validateIfTableHasData(SQLiteDatabase myDatabase,String tableName){
    Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName,null);
    return c.moveToFirst();
}
```

Comment: For performance reason I would suggest to add a "LIMIT 1".

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you can do it** -

```
if(checkTable("TABLE"))
{
  //table exists fill data.
}
```

**Method to check table** -

```
public static boolean checkTable(String table) {
Cursor cur2 = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select name from sqlite_master where name='"
        + table + "'", null);

if (cur2.getCount() != 0) {
    if (!cur2.isClosed())
        cur2.close();
    return true;
} else {
    if (!cur2.isClosed())
        cur2.close();
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: // db.close(); whts that?

Comment: that's the commented line. You can skip that for your purpose. Deleted  for your purpose.

Comment: This will check whether the table exists, not whether it has data in it.

Comment: yeah laalto is right it is everytime return else statement if using existing asset database.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this solution is better:

```
    boolean flag;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    try {
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    String count = "SELECT * FROM table";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(count, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        flag = false;
    } else {
        flag = true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();

    return flag;
```

`moveToFirst()` check table and return `true`, if table is empty. Answer that is marked correct - uses extra check.

Comment: Please include an explanation of your answer.

Comment: @xpereta moveToFirst() check table and return true, if table is empty.

Comment: @xpereta `moveToFirst()` check table and return `true`, if table is empty.

Comment: Please, include the explanation in the actual answer, not in the comments. Also explain why you say it's better that the other answers.