# Android with Sqlite - How to check if table exist and if empty

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, alert

I want to show an alertbox if the table does not exist or the table content is empty.

To check if the table is empty I'm using:

```
        cCheckDB = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + MainActivity.TABLE_NAME +"", null);

        if (cCheckDB != null) {
            cCheckDB.moveToFirst();

            if (cCheckDB.getInt (0) == 0) {
                // EMPTY
            }
        }
```

But **how to wrap this in an "if table exist"? What is the best way?**

I know both ways to check if a table exist or to check if there is content in it. But I want to use the checks in a meaningful and way and not in single query if this is possible - that's my question.

Comment: Please check this flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058909/how-does-one-check-if-a-table-exists-in-an-android-sqlite-database

Comment: Sure I can catch the Exception or create if not exist but this is not helpfull in my case. I thought there is another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope,This will be helpful to you. **It's working well!!!**

```
public boolean isTableExists(String tableName, boolean openDb) {
    if(openDb) {
        if(mDatabase == null || !mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }

        if(!mDatabase.isReadOnly()) {
            mDatabase.close();
            mDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
                    cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Its working. I can use this to check if  the table is empty after that

Comment: it only check table existance.

Comment: I wanted to combine both checks but it looks like this is not possible. So Ill use this function with a if clause to check the content after that. This is for me the best solution

Answer (score 2):

To check that your table exists or not, you can use:

**`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';`**

here, replace table_name with your table name you want to change

EX:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Employee_Details';
```

Comment: check my edited answer. it will give you result if that table exists

Comment: So ill have to seperate one table check and one check if table is empty. Is there no other way to combine  these two checks?

Comment: if table doest exist than there is no need to check whether it is empty or not than check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630307/sqlite-check-if-table-is-empty

Comment: If Im using a select query on an non existing table ill get a null pointer

Comment: what you need to do is, first check if table exists or not than you can check for data in that table.+

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is most helpfull

Comment: Akash Patel was faster

Comment: okay but he has copied complete answer from above link. it can be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**the more optimal way is to check if table exist then check if record exist or not**

```
 private void clearTable(String tableName) {
        int count;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND " +
                "name= " + tableName, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        count = cursor.getInt(0);
        if (!cursor.isClosed())
            cursor.close();

        if (count > 0)//table exist now delete record if it exist
        {
            cursor=db.rawQuery("select exists(select 1 FROM " + tableName + ")", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
            if (!cursor.isClosed())
                cursor.close();
            if (count > 0)
                db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any clue to combine theres two meaningful? Thats what I would like to know :)

Comment: check my edited answer i tested it in sqlite tool in firefox

Comment: you need to check if table exists first than check for record existence because there is no combine query for checking table existance and record together. till i searched.