# Check if a table is empty on SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm trying to adapt to VB.NET the code of the most voted answer from this post:

[Sqlite Check if Table is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630307/sqlite-check-if-table-is-empty)

Original code is

```
SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();
String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM table";
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
mcursor.moveToFirst();
int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
if(icount>0)
//leave 
else
//populate table
```

My code looks like ('Only to have a message on the screen I will fill the If - Else code later')

```vb
Using conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDataBase.sqlite;Version=3;foreign keys=true")

Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim emptyUserTable = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersTable"
    Dim cmdIsEmpty As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(emptyUserTable, conn)

    Try
        Dim Answer As Integer
        Answer = cmdIsEmpty.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(Answer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Using
```

But the "Answer" is allways -1, with empty table or not.

I don´t know how to use getWritableDataBase because I get a 
getWritableDatabase is not a member of SQLiteConnection

The same with rawQuery.

**How can I check if usersTable is empty or not on VB.NET?**

Comment: This is a query. Why are you calling Execute**NonQuery**?

Comment: @CL. ups! Do I need to fix the code with ExecuteReader instead? I don't understand why getWritable and rawQuery didn't work as the samples I read

Comment: `getWritableDatabase` and `rawQuery` are functions in the Android framework. Are you using VB.NET for Android?

Comment: @CL Thanks again for the info. I'm using just standard VB.NET on Visual Studio, my trouble is I can´t find a sample for VB.NET, all the code around is for Java, C or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've abstracted your code a little so it can be used for any table:

```vb
Private Function IsTableEmpty(tblName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sql = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tblName)

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr)
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

            conn.Open()

            Dim rows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            Return rows = 0
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
If IsTableEmpty("usersTable") Then
    Console.Beep()
End If
```

Notes

- The command object should be disposed when you are done with it, so it is used on a Using block.
- There is not need to copy your connection string everywhere.  You can define it once as a form/class level variable and reuse it everywhere
- `ExecuteScalar()` gets the count back, then it is tested for 0 rows

Comment: Worked without any change! Wow, a lot of code needed for a simple request. The {0} works as a parameter for the tblName and String.Format is for glue both parts. Your recommendations was noted as well Thanks!

Comment: Why I can´t use the @ before your name?

Comment: I guess is also possible to use something like                 `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()"
lastID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: a) `String.Format` is a cleaner way to glue strings together; if the data was in a DataTable, you could just use `Rows.Count` b) no need to ping the owner of the post c) Dont use `last_insert_rowid()`: it *returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection* It works to get the id of a row just added.  On a connection you just opened, it will always be zed

Comment: Also note that if/when you want the Id of the last inserted record, you do not have to run a query: `myConnection.LastInsertRowId` should have the value (just dont close the connection before trying to read it)

Comment: Great answer as allways